# Ubuntu 17.10 installer crashes shortly after startup

Tags: boot, system-installation, radeon, amd-graphics, 17.10

**Specs:**

CPU: AMD FX-6300 Black Edition (stock settings)

Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-990FXA-UD3 rev. 4 (IOMMU controller enabled)

RAM: Corsair Vengeance 1866 MHz CAS 10 2x8 GiB kit (XMP enabled)

Graphics card: MSI Radeon R9 390 GAMING 8G

**Problem description**

When attempting to use either the "Install Ubuntu" or the "Try Ubuntu without installing" option of the Ubuntu 17.10 amd64 default installer, after displaying the Ubuntu splash screen and loading symbol, the installer abruptly cuts to a blank screen. This either occurs immediately after startup completes or a few seconds later, with no pattern that I have yet discerned. Visual artifacts in the form of horizontal and vertical lines generally accompany one of these crashes. I am able to use Windows 10 Home 64-bit (build 15063.674) with this computer and have encountered no similar issues using that operating system.

**Troubleshooting steps taken**

1.) I enabled EHCI handoff. There was no change in behavior.

2.) I burned the installer image to an optical disc, rather than using [Unetbootin 655](https://unetbootin.github.io/). There was no change in behavior.

3.) I booted the installer in legacy mode. There was no change in behavior.

Comment: After trying Papyrcat's proposed solution, the installer worked, but the installed copy of Ubuntu crashes in the same manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get to the GRUB menu, hit "e". Then replace `quiet splash` with `nomodeset` and hit F10. You should be able to install from there. As far as getting the GPU working after that point, though, I dunno. I've got a 390 and the same issue and this is as far as I've got.

Comment: I now have an installed copy of Ubuntu that crashes almost immediately. That's slightly better than before, at least. Thanks for your help.